# Filter Excel column for cells that contain various combinations of characters

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to filter a range in Excel, say DATA, based on if cells in another column, say CHECKBOXES are checked via a checkbox. It would look something like this:

**DATA**
aa 
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc

**CHECKBOXES**
a [x]
b [x]
c [x]

So, if 'a' were checked under the CHECKBOXES column, the DATA column would show  cells that only contained the letter a, not 'b' or 'c'. But if 'a' and 'b' were checked, the DATA column would show cells that contained either the letters a **OR** b, but not 'c'. If all three 'a', 'b', and 'c' were checked, there would obviously not be any filtering needed.

I would like to implement this across a large range of data with both columns. 
Any and all help is much appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this the way you've described.

1. Filtering requires a columns header. Data would have to start in row 2, not row 1.
2. Filtering or hiding can only be performed on full rows or full columns. If the *A's* were hidden, your checkboxes in C1:C3 would also be hidden.

Rethink your proposal and try to accomplish something towards a solution. If you run into trouble, edit your post to include new details.

> if 'a' were checked under the CHECKBOXES column, the DATA column would show cells that only contained the letter a, not 'b' or 'c'. But if 'a' and 'b' were checked, the DATA column would show cells that contained either the letters a OR b, but not 'c'. If all three 'a', 'b', and 'c' were checked, there would obviously not be any filtering needed.

Here's a method that works.

- Use Developer, Controls, Insert to add three **ActiveX Checkboxes**. Do **not** add Form Control Checkboxes and do **not** add Option buttons of any kind.
- One by one, right-click the **ActiveX Checkboxes** and access the Properties. Change the Names to *CheckBoxA, CheckBoxB* and *CheckBoxC* and the Captions to *A, B* and *C*.
- Resize the checkboxes as appropriate and position them in the top row where they will not be hidden by filtering values. When you're happy with the results, click Developer, Controls, Design Mode to exit Design Mode.
- Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose View Code. Paste in the following.

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub CheckBoxABC_Click()

      Dim i As Long, dict As Object, str As String

      Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

      If AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False

      With Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

          For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
              'store the cell value
              str = .Cells(i, "A").Value

              'see if it might belong and add it
              If CBool(InStr(1, str, "A", vbTextCompare)) And .Parent.CheckBoxA Then _
                  dict.Item(str) = vbNullString
              If CBool(InStr(1, str, "B", vbTextCompare)) And .Parent.CheckBoxB Then _
                  dict.Item(str) = vbNullString
              If CBool(InStr(1, str, "C", vbTextCompare)) And .Parent.CheckBoxC Then _
                  dict.Item(str) = vbNullString

              'see if it doesn't belong and remove it
              If dict.Exists(str) And CBool(InStr(1, str, "A", vbTextCompare)) And Not .Parent.CheckBoxA Then _
                  dict.Remove str
              If dict.Exists(str) And CBool(InStr(1, str, "B", vbTextCompare)) And Not .Parent.CheckBoxB Then _
                  dict.Remove str
              If dict.Exists(str) And CBool(InStr(1, str, "C", vbTextCompare)) And Not .Parent.CheckBoxC Then _
                  dict.Remove str

          Next i

          If dict.Count > 0 Then
              .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=dict.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=False
          Else
              .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Z", VisibleDropDown:=False
          End If

      End With
  End Sub

  Private Sub CheckBoxA_Click()
      CheckBoxABC_Click
  End Sub

  Private Sub CheckBoxB_Click()
      CheckBoxABC_Click
  End Sub

  Private Sub CheckBoxC_Click()
      CheckBoxABC_Click
  End Sub
  ```
- Your results should be similar to the following.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I have adjusted my post based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! I have also managed to make it work in GoogleSheets via the =FILTER function, with some tweaking. Unfortunately this feature is not yet available in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Well this can be done a few different ways. However, this is one way you can acomplish what you are trying to do. 
Create three checkboxes by using design mode from the developer tab and then simply assign 3 macros to do the 3 different buttons. You can also just create one sub and than just have that one sub(macro) do all the work. Is really up to you.

```
 Sub OptionButton1_Click()

 Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=a*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub

Sub OptionButton2_Click()
 Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=b*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub

Sub option3_click()
 Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=c*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, and I have tried what you suggest. It works to an extent. The problem is that I would like Column A to filter cells that only contain characters matching the checked boxes. So, as in the picture you provided, if 'a' is checked, then only 'aa' should show in the filtered column. If 'a'  and 'c' are checked, then the filtered column would show any cell that has any combination of 'a' and 'c'.